# kotlin coroutines: runBlocking in kotlin global.launch

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

is this a wrong usage about runBlocking?
as "runBlocking" docs says `This function should not be used from coroutine`.

this code snippnet is from [camerakit-android](https://github.com/CameraKit/camerakit-android/blob/master/camerakit/src/main/java/com/camerakit/CameraPreview.kt) library.

```
    fun start(facing: CameraFacing) {
        GlobalScope.launch(cameraDispatcher) {
            runBlocking {
                lifecycleState = LifecycleState.STARTED
                cameraFacing = facing
                openCamera()
            }
        }
    }
```

after I delete runBlocking ,it can't work.
So what's `runBlocking`'s meaning here?

Comment: what do you mean, by "it can't work"?

Comment: How is `openCamera()` defined? Is it a suspending function or a `CoroutineScope` extension? Does it launch coroutines?

Answer (score 2):

### General case: use coroutineScope instead of runBlocking

As a general rule, if you're already in the context of a coroutine (in a suspending function), you should always favor suspending over blocking. That's why, as you noted, the use of `runBlocking` is discouraged from within coroutines because it unnecessarily blocks the current thread.

So, anytime you feel like you need `runBlocking` inside a suspending function, you should use [`coroutineScope`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/coroutine-scope.html) instead. It's the suspending equivalent of `runBlocking`, because it waits for all child coroutines to finish their execution before returning:

```
    fun start(facing: CameraFacing) {
        GlobalScope.launch(cameraDispatcher) {
            coroutineScope {
                lifecycleState = LifecycleState.STARTED
                cameraFacing = facing
                openCamera()
            }
        }
    }
```

### Your case: missing structured concurrency?

In your specific case, since you say it "can't work" without `runBlocking`, I suspect `openCamera()` starts coroutines on its own.

The best practice for starting coroutines is [structured concurrency](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/basics.html#structured-concurrency). This means launching coroutines as children of a current coroutine instead of launching global coroutines with `GlobalScope`.

If `openCamera()` uses the `GlobalScope` to start a coroutine, you won't be able to wait for it to finish unless using `runBlocking`, because even if `coroutineScope` provides a scope, it won't be used when calling `GlobalScope.launch`.

Just to be clear, what prevents you from using `coroutineScope` here (and forces you to use `runBlocking`) is not being *inside* a `GlobalScope.launch`, but it is calling a function that itself uses `GlobalScope.launch` (I suspect `openCamera()` does this here).

If you really want to do things right:

- declare `openCamera()` and `start()` as extensions of `CoroutineScope`
- remove all `GlobalScope` usages, use `launch` with the implicit receiver being the scope you now have
- use `coroutineScope` instead of `runBlocking` to suspend instead of blocking

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is wrong because it annuls everything coroutines have to offer. It is a more complex and messy way of writing

```
yourJavaExecutor.submit {
    lifecycleState = LifecycleState.STARTED
    cameraFacing = facing
    openCamera()
}
```

In other words, you do nothing but submit a blocking task to a background thread.